# How to construct an XPath to identify and click on an element using Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriver

I want to access and click on the following HTML code elements.

I tried:

```
driver.FindElement(By.ClassName("all_excel")).Click();
```

But an error occurs.
I'd appreciate it if you could give me a solution.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <a href="#" class="btn all_excel _excelDownloadBtn _click(nmp.checkout_admin.order.n.sale.delivery.excelDownload()) _stopDefault"><span class="blind">all excel download</span></a>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: *But an error occurs*. I think it helps if you can add the exact error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use below locator:

```
driver.FindElement(By.Xpath("//a[.='all excel download']")).Click();

// or use css selector
driver.FindElement(By.Css("a[class*='_excelDownloadBtn']")).Click();
```